# HTML5 Offline Application Manifest Usage in an IFrame

Tags: caching, html

I'm doing some work with html 5's offline application cache using firefox 3.6.  My web application uses iframes to load other web application that pass the same-origin policy requirement. Unfortunately, the offline application cache for the iframe loaded page does not work.  Specifically:

- For the url sourced in via an iframe, I observe the application manifest and all of resources listed inside of it being loaded from my webserver.
- When I load the url of the iframe directly by typing it into my URL bar, the application cache works.
- When the page that has the application cache is loaded via an iframe, the application cache does not work.
- The only difference between the container page url and the iframe src url is the web application context (i.e. container is 'https://www.example.com/cat' while iframe source url is 'https://www.example.com/dog').

I did find some chatter on a [whatwg working group thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/whatwg@lists.whatwg.org/msg12016.html) discussing whether iframe's should inherit container manifest settings, which leads me to believe that this ought to work.

Am I doing something unreasomnable?  Is firefox lagging behind the whatwg specification?  Any ideas or pointers to a solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out the problem and filed a bug ticket with firefox:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=623996